I am getting an internal server error when i use mac2 driver with appium
The webdiver.Remote option is working but the appium server returns an 500.if anyone wants more context then i can send them the logs. look at my code once if i did a mistake:
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.common import AppiumOptions

# Set up the desired capabilities
options = AppiumOptions()
options.set_capability("platformName", "mac")
options.set_capability("automationName", "mac2")
options.set_capability("app", "/System/Applications/Calculator.app")

# Create the WebDriver instance (this is where the error happens)
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", options=options)

and from the server i get this response:
[87a9f913][WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:10100
[87a9f913][WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[87a9f913][WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:10100/status] with no body
[87a9f913][WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:10100
[87a9f913][WebDriverAgentMac] Mac2Driver session cannot be stopped, because the server is not running
[87a9f913][AppiumDriver@4271] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1724381199314 (08:31:39 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time))
[87a9f913][AppiumDriver@4271] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Mac2Driver server is not listening within 120000ms timeout. Try to increase the value of 'serverStartupTimeout' capability, check the server logs and make sure the xcodebuild host process could be started manually from a terminal
    at WDAMacServer.startSession (/Users/dhakalrabi/.appium/node_modules/appium-mac2-driver/lib/wda-mac.js:432:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Mac2Driver.createSession (/Users/dhakalrabi/.appium/node_modules/appium-mac2-driver/lib/driver.js:120:7)
    at AppiumDriver.createSession (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:731:35)
[87a9f913][HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 120052 ms - 964 


if anyone knows please help me.
i tried almost everything from asking it to chatgpt, looking at many yt tutorials, searching the issue in google but i got nothing. i think this is an unique problem maybe or something.

I actually fixed it. i just had to install xcode :3
